# How to customize Azure function url

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Just got started with azure functions. I am using it as an httptrigger for an IoT device.

I am trying to setup one function that will work for httptrigger requests coming from several IoT devices - So I dont have to setup one function per device. So ideally, in my c# file, I will have something like this:

```
DeviceClient deviceClient;
string iotHubUri = "myhub";
string deviceName = "something dynamic here that changes with device";
string deviceKey = "something dynamic here that changes with device";
```

Then , I'd like to get my function url to look something like this:

```
"https://<functionapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function>/{device_id}?code=xxxxx"
```

where device_id is the IoT device id.

I am not sure how to first setup the reference in the c# file to be dynamic and also how to get the url to look the way I intend.

Some help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There is a route parameter is HTTP trigger exactly for this. Your trigger definition should look something like this:

```json
"bindings": [
  {
    "type": "httpTrigger",
    "route": "something/{deviceid}",
    "name": "request",
    // possibly other parameters
  }
],
```

If you are using precompiled C# functions, you can do the same via attribute property, e.g.

```cs
public static IActionResult Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET", Route = "something/{deviceid}")] 
    HttpRequest request,
    string deviceid)
{
    // do something based on device id
}
```

Comment: Mikhail - I am looking to just add the deviceid - so do I need the "something" part? In anycase, when I add "route": "something/{deviceid}", it is shown literally in the url string. The device id is not showing the id of the IoT device. Or maybe I misunderstand how this should work?

Comment: "something" is not required, it's because of <function> in your URL requirement. You can request `http://youappurl/api/mydev123` and your function gets called with `mydev123` as `deviceid` argument value.

Comment: If i add "route": "{deviceid}",  - it shows up in the url as http://youappurl/api/(deviceid}.  The actual device id is not shown. Am I missing something?

Comment: Go ahead, replace {deviceid} with an id and request that URL from a browser or postman

Comment: Getting a 401 unauthroized message.

Comment: What do I do with this in my run.csx file

DeviceClient deviceClient;
    string iotHubUri = "myhub";
    string deviceName = "xxx";
    string deviceKey = "xx";

its currently hard coded. shouldnt that be dynamic too?

Comment: That really depends on your scenario details. I would expect some lookup of those parameters based on `deviceid`? Or you can accept them in URL template too, if they are input parameters. We shouldn't be doing so many comments... If you need more details, extend your question, or post a new one if it's different.

Answer (score 3):

## Customize your Azure function route

To customize your url you can use two files, the one in which is defined the function `function.json` and the `host.json`.

#### function.json suffix

in `function.json` you can define the base url adding to the bindings array the `"route": "yourbaseurl"` property. that should result in something like this

```
{
  "scriptFile": "../dist/server.js",
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "cool", ///// This is the line that you have to add /////
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### host.json prefix

On the `host.json`file you can add a prefix to that route, let's say you want to add a fancy name group or so...

therefore your file should look something like this

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {    
        "routePrefix": "prefix" ///// here is that you include your prefix route /////
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

## I just want one word or none

if you want to have just one word in your route leave the `host.json` `"routePrefix": ""` and the `function.json` `"route": "therouteyouwant"` or empty like `"route": ""`.